# No activity found exception when send sms only in Samsung Marshmallow devices

Tags: android

I'm working on the android app in which i need to send the sms with image using intent but i'm getting exception ActivityNotFoundException. In all devices working fine but in samsung devices with marshmallow version not working.
Here is my code.

```
  Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
    sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms","com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
    sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Miimoji sent from your friend");
    sendIntent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM", Uri.parse("file://" + fileName));
    sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
```

And here is the errorReport.

> 02-17 02:32:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   02-17 02:32:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shareviamms/com.example.shareviamms.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>   02-17 02:32:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2187)
>   02-17 02:32:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237)
>   02-17 02:32:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:146)
>   02-17 02:32:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1239)
>   02-17 02:32:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   02-17 02:32:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   02-17 02:32:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5085)
>   02-17 02:32:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   02-17 02:32:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   02-17 02:32:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   02-17 02:32:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   02-17 02:32:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   02-17 02:32:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>   02-17 02:32:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
>   02-17 02:32:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
>   02-17 02:32:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
>   02-17 02:32:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
>   02-17 02:32:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
>   02-17 02:32:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
>   02-17 02:32:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at com.example.shareviamms.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
>   02-17 02:32:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
>   02-17 02:32:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>   02-17 02:32:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2151)
>   02-17 02:32:55.332: E/AndroidRuntime(11322):  ... 11 more

Comment: Don't specify the class name. There's no guarantee that that `Activity` - or even that package - will be on any given device, as you're seeing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably Samsung devices use something else than `com.android.mms`

Actually you can do it just with

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

Instead of

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms","com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
```

In other case you can catch android.content.ActivityNotFoundException and use Samsung default mms way.

Answer (score 1):

You incorrectly assume that `com.android.mms` package must be present on the device (not to mention you miss `try/catch`). So this line is not guaranteed to be pointing to valid app:

```
sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms","com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
```

and even if it would, then assumption `ComposeMessageActivity` will be available for you is also wrong.

Proper way of sending stuff out is by using [SmsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html), i.e.:

```
SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();  
sms.sendTextMessage(...)
```

Comment: Using `SmsManager` is a completely different thing, and will require an additional permission. There's nothing inherently wrong, or improper, with sending via `Intent`.